# How to generate tiles using gdal2tiles that can be used for google.maps.ImageMapType?

Tags: gdal, google-maps-api, gdal2tiles

Using GDAL tools such as **gdal2tiles.py**, allows one to generate map tiles from a single image file.

However, the tiles generated by gdal2tiles doesn't seem to be like one used for [google.maps.ImageMapType Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)

How to generate tiles using gdal2tiles that can be used for google.maps.ImageMapType?